# Is this part of a set?

Tags: set-identification

[image]

Are those pieces part of a set?
Or a random build of something?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The 'Red Slope, Curved 4 x 2 with White and Yellow Flames Pattern Model' part (right side of the picture, on the roof) comes in 2 variants: [Left](https://www.bricklink.com/v2/catalog/catalogitem.page?P=93606pb004L&name=Slope,%20Curved%204%20x%202%20with%20White%20and%20Yellow%20Flames%20Pattern%20Model%20Left%20Side%20(Sticker)%20-%20Set%209441&category=%5BSlope,%20Curved,%20Decorated%5D#T=C&C=5) and [Right](https://www.bricklink.com/v2/catalog/catalogitem.page?P=93606pb004R&name=Slope,%20Curved%204%20x%202%20with%20White%20and%20Yellow%20Flames%20Pattern%20Model%20Right%20Side%20(Sticker)%20-%20Set%209441&category=%5BSlope,%20Curved,%20Decorated%5D#T=C&C=5).  However, both of these parts only exist in the same 1 set, [9441: Kai's Blade Cycle](https://www.bricklink.com/v2/catalog/catalogitem.page?S=9441-1#T=S&O=%7B%22iconly%22:0%7D)

[image: Kai's Blade Cycle Set]

Similarly, the 'Tail Shuttle with Lightning Pattern' (left side of the picture - also comes in [Left](https://www.bricklink.com/v2/catalog/catalogitem.page?P=6239pb035L&idColor=63&name=Dark%20Blue%20Tail%20Shuttle%20with%20Lightning%20Pattern%20on%20Left%20Side%20(Sticker)%20-%20Set%209442&category=%5BTail,%20Decorated%5D#T=C&C=63) and [Right](https://www.bricklink.com/v2/catalog/catalogitem.page?P=6239pb035R&idColor=63&name=Dark%20Blue%20Tail%20Shuttle%20with%20Lightning%20Pattern%20on%20Right%20Side%20(Sticker)%20-%20Set%209442&category=%5BTail,%20Decorated%5D#T=C&C=63) variants) come from [9442: Jay's Storm Fighter](https://www.bricklink.com/v2/catalog/catalogitem.page?S=9442-1#T=I)

[image: Jay's Storm Fighter Set]
(This also appears to be where those 2 large blue plates are from)

As such, this model must be a Maker's Own Creation (MOC), and not an official LEGO set.  So, yes, a 'random build of something'

Both of the sets listed are from the [LEGO Ninjago: Rise of the Snakes](https://www.bricklink.com/catalogList.asp?catType=S&catString=759.945) series